# Sending POST parameters between PHP files using AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a PHP file test.php that has a simple link, which after being clicked, calls an AJAX function to send data as POST parameters to another file testPHP.php. The second file then receives the POST parameters from the AJAX call and then alerts the contents inside the $_POST array. The issue I am facing is that in the second file, the $_POST array is empty (I checked that using print_r($_POST)), so I think that the data hasn't passed through. 
These are the 2 files:

test.php

```
  <a id="link" role="button" href="testPHP.php">Test</a>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  $("#link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('function entered');
    $.ajax({
     url: "testPHP.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        parameter1: 'test', 
        parameter2: 'test2'},
      success: function(msg) {
        alert('wow' + msg);
      }

    });
    alert('function end');
    document.getElementById('#link').setAttribute('href','testPHP.php');
  });
```

testPHP.php

```
if(isset($_GET))
{
  echo "<script>alert('GET is there');</script>";
  print_r($_GET);
}
if(isset($_POST))
{
  echo "<script>alert('POST is there')</script>";
  print_r($_POST);
}
if(isset($_POST['parameter1']))
{
  echo "<script>alert('$_POST is set')</script>";
  header('Location: HomePage.php');
}
else
{
  echo "<script>alert('No post variable set')</script>";
}
```

What I have tried so far is to send a SUCCESS message if the AJAX call has been executed successfully, and it does alert me the Success message. I have also checked to see the contents of the $_POST array in the 2nd file to see if I am receiving data in a format other than a POST request (like a string that might have to be exploded to get the contents), but the $_POST array comes up empty.
This is the output I get when it redirects to the 2nd page: 
Array() Array() 
The $_POST and $_GET (for testing purpose) arrays come up empty.

I have also gone through the AJAX documentation, but can't get this simple POST data transfer to work. Can someone please help me with this issue so that I can understand how to properly send POST parameters and receive the data into $_POST['parameter1'] and $_POST['parameter2'] strings so I can process the data further.

**Note**: I have used the FORM's POST method using hidden form elements and that works fine, but I want to try this approach to better understand how AJAX works.

Comment: put `console.log(msg);` in your success function and use your browser's console to see the data. What does it say?

Comment: console.log(msg) shows the entire code of other PHP files in the same folder. 
It's too long to be copied here but the code starts like this 
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> .............................

Comment: I think your looking at the inspector and not the console look for the console tab

Comment: I am afraid that's the content displayed in the console. For confirming it, I also printed "Test" alongside msg in success function, and it displayed "Test" after the entire code.

Comment: That just don't sound right at all....What browser are you using

Comment: I am using Chrome, Version 71.0.3578.98

Comment: Why not? he redirects his AJAX to the page, when the page loads it sends the HTML in the msg, this is not clear what you are trying to do, why you redirect your AJAX to some other page?

Comment: I am trying to redirect AJAX to another page to send it's data to that page, isn't that the way we do it?

Comment: @Art3mix According to his code he should only be receiving some alerts and the print_r's he should not be receiving any html in his message, it is simply not there.

Comment: I haven't used PHP in a while, but if you do an ajax to X.php, and in X.php you redirect to Y.php, the ajax will return the Y.php html to the success code, no? (or the response of Y.php php code) @Joseph_J

Comment: @Tribunal When you do an AJAX to a X.php, the response from the X.php will go to the success function parameter (msg in your case), so if you do `echo "ok"`, msg variable will contain `"ok"`, so you are trying to do an alert inside the alert, i simply don't understand what you are trying to do here, can you explain what you need from the ajax?

Comment: @Art3mix I don't know the answer to that.. You could be right...

Comment: I just need this AJAX call to be able to send data as POST to another PHP file on the click of a button in the first file. The other echo's are just for testing purpose, the main purpose is to be able to send the 2 parameters 'parameter1' and 'parameter2' as POST parameters and to be able to receive them in the form of $_POST['parameter1'] and $_POST['parameter2'] in the 2nd file

Comment: I would use RamRaider's answer to troubleshoot.  Also I think you will find using the console to debug is hands down better than sending alerts through your code to debug.

Comment: Well, there are different ways to achieve this, but header() is not one of them, when you header() you redirect the request to another page, so all the headers are cleared and your POST is deleted.
You can require the page require("HomePage.php"), and that page code will be available to your in your "testPHP.php" code, that why you will be able to use both pages codes. or you will need to do a separate CURL request to "HomePage.php", again i don't know the use case so its hard to give any more info, but the current answers won't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different version of the above which should help you solve your problem. For ease in debugging it is all one page but you can clearly see the script in operation once you click the button. Simply `echo`ing javascript in the php code and hoping it will execute client side is not going to work - simply echo a message or a JSON object would be better.

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();

        print_r( $_POST );

        exit();
    }

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery - ajax experiments</title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <a id='link' role='button' href='#'>Test</a>
        <script>
            $('#link').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('function entered');
                $.ajax({
                    url: location.href,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        parameter1: 'test', 
                        parameter2: 'test2'
                    },
                    success: function(msg) {
                        alert( 'wow' + msg );
                    }

                });
                alert('function end');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As 2 separate pages ( both in same directory otherwise edit page to the ajax target )

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery - ajax experiments</title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <a id='link' role='button' href='#'>Test</a>
        <br /><br />
        <script>
            $('#link').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'jquery-ajax-target.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        parameter1: 'test', 
                        parameter2: 'test2'
                    },
                    success: function(msg) {
                        alert( 'wow' + msg );
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the ajax target, `jquery-ajax-target.php`

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();

        $parameter1=( isset( $_POST['parameter1'] ) ) ? $_POST['parameter1'] : false;
        $parameter2=( isset( $_POST['parameter2'] ) ) ? $_POST['parameter2'] : false;


        $_POST['modified']=array(
            'p1'=>sprintf('modified %s', strrev( $parameter1 ) ),
            'p2'=>sprintf('modified %s', strrev( $parameter2 ) )
        );


        $json=json_encode( $_POST );
        echo $json;

        exit();
    }

?>
```

Comment: This works as a single file, can you tell me how to make it work on 2 different files? I tried to change the href="#" to href="indexPHP.php" and then using the first section of PHP code inside indexPHP.php but the page does not redirect to the 2nd page after clicking the link.

Comment: The 2 different pages solution does not work, maybe the href="#" was redirecting it to the same page, so I changed that to the 2nd file location and it still does not redirect there, it just alerts the contents of the $_POST.

Comment: works fine for me - with the `#` too. The `e.preventDefault()` should stop the `#` href attribute ever being reached

Comment: Could you give an explanation as to what does the code do basically? I was under the impression that we are sending $_POST data to another PHP file and then after redirecting to that file, we can extract $_POST['parameter1'] and $_POST['parameter2'] and display that, but I am sure it's not what's happening here

Comment: there is no `redirection` going on - otherwise what would be the point of the ajax in this instance? By clicking the `#link` you are correct in that a POST request is sent to the other page. The other page processes the POST request, does some fudging around with the data and sends a response. The response is then processed by the ajax callback function...simples...

Comment: This callback function, is it the success() method mentioned in the AJAX module and msg being the processed response?

Comment: yes - generally the `success` function is referred to as the `callback`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and the quick response. The sample template provided was useful in clearing the misconception I had about AJAX. I had one more doubt though, what happens if we don't specify a success() method? Will the flow of control shift to the 2nd PHP file permanently?

Comment: I don't use jQuery as such so not 100% sure what would happen but I suspect the request would be made but you would never receive and visual clues in the client app nor be able to continue processing the DOM as would often be the case. Give it a go - use a method ( in PHP ) such as `file_put_contents` to write to a file - if the file gets written to and you have no callback then assume it safe to omit the callback

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version.  It will return a JSON response to your ajax which will be visible in your console for easy debugging.

Your main page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link" role="button" href="#">Test</a>

<script>


$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('function entered');
    $.ajax({
     url: "testPHP.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json', //This tells your ajax that you are expecting a json formatted string as a response.
      data: {
        parameter1: 'test', 
        parameter2: 'test2'
      },
      success: function(msg) {
        console.log(msg); //This will show the results as an object in your console.

      }

    });
    console.log('Function End');
    //document.getElementById('#link').setAttribute('href','testPHP.php'); //Why are you doing this. It's not needed.
  });

});


</script>
```

Your testPHP.php page:

```
$results = array();

if(isset($_GET)){


  $results[] = array(

    'GET' => 'TRUE',
    'getData' => $_GET   

  ); 

}

if(isset($_POST)){

  $results[] = array(

    'POST' => 'TRUE',
    'postData' => $_POST   

  ); 

}

echo json_encode($results);
```

Here is an explanation of what is happening:

You make an initial call to your ajax by triggering some event.  In your case it is the click of the link.

The click function leads to the actual ajax call which simply sends a post request to the `testPHP.php`.

The `testPHP.php` receives the post request and performs some sort of operation with the data that was provided by the ajax call.

The `testPHP.php` then sends back some sort of answer back to the ajax function.  The data will be available in the success function.

You then get to decide how to use the data that was passed back from the `testPHP.php` page to the success function.

This is all done without your original page's code being refreshed.

You are not actually redirecting your user to another page.. You are just telling your page to goto another page and do some operation, which then gets reported back to the original page for you to do something with.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about how this AJAX function works, I have gotten the general idea now and intend to explore further. Unfortunately since I am new to Stack Overflow, my upvotes have been recorded but cannot be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It does work after removing type attribute on script tag. I am using `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` before main script tag. It is working here. Also close the script tag. I hope I can help.
Also change the

> `document.getElementById('#link').setAttribute('href','testPHP.php');`

to

`document.getElementById('link').setAttribute('href','testPHP.php');`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are using javascript to change the attribute and in javascript once you used `getElementById` you no longer have to use `#` sign. try the following and it will work fine.

```php
<?php

if(isset($_GET))
{
    echo "<script>alert('GET is there');</script>";
    print_r($_GET);
}
if(isset($_POST))
{
    echo "<script>alert('POST is there')</script>";
    print_r($_POST);
}
if(isset($_POST['parameter1']))
{
    echo "<script>alert('$_POST is set')</script>";
    header('Location: HomePage.php');
}
else
{
    echo "<script>alert('No post variable set')</script>";
}
?>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<a id="link" role="button" href="index2.php">Test</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#link").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('function entered');
        $.ajax({
            url: "testPHP.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                parameter1: 'test',
                parameter2: 'test2'},
            success: function(msg) {
                alert('wow' + msg);
            }

        });
        alert('function end');
        document.getElementById('link').setAttribute('href','testPHP.php');

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Furthermore** it's a good practice to use the `failed callback` for the request.

```
 error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    alert(" Can't do because: " + error);
},
```